# What is the difference between 看不起 and 看不上?

Tags: usage, difference, equivalent-phrase

The two have very similar meanings and can both be used to mean "detest, despise, look down upon" but there seems to be a subtle difference.

According to these entries:

看不起 http://www.zdic.net/c/b/149/321190.htm

看不上 http://www.zdic.net/c/b/164/364508.htm

看不上 can also carry the meaning of "cannot suit for one’s idea". There's also a [blog post](http://blog.sina.com.cn/s/blog_7eac08a701012ydt.html) that states that 看不起 is more of an objective judgement whereas 看不上 is more subjective, hence the latter could simply mean something is not up to the speaker's standards. However I'm not entirely convinced, and was hoping there were better sources outlining the differences between the two.

Comment: As a native speaker, when I hear A看不起B, it means 'A despise B because B is bad (at subject X)', while A看不上B means 'A doesn't think B is as good (at subject X) as A himself, but B is not necessarily bad'. In other word, 'B is inferior than most' vs. 'B inferior than A'. This is my personal understanding and could be wrong, just a data point for you.

Comment: When A看不起B, it means A **looks down on** B. B has to be a person whom A considers as inferior. When A看不上B, it usually means A has **no desire** for B. B can be an object or a person. Both are subjective in nature as it is from A's personal point of view.

Comment: @QuestionOverflow 'no desire' is the most accurate translation for 看不上 so far, IMO. Another supporting example is 'A不想和B玩，因为A___B', 看不起 here means A finds B cheating or unsporting or having other behavioral problems; 看不上 means A find B's skill not as good as an interesting game requires.

Answer (score 6):

I am not a linguist. So I can only give you my perspective as a native Chinese speaker.

To make it short: 看不起 is **rarely used on an object**, whereas 看不上 **can be used on both persons and objects.**

**Some examples:**

1. 我最 *看不起* 他这种自私的人。 **CORRECT**
2. 我最 *看不上* 他这种自私的人。 **CORRECT**
3. 品味一向很高的她根本 *看不上* 这种便宜货。 **CORRECT**
4. 品味一向很高的她根本 *看不起* 这种便宜货。 **Understandable but AWKWARD**

Comment: Which one is more similar to 小看？

Comment: @tao  i would say neither. 小看 is usually used in its negative form. e.g. 别小看我。 不要小看他。

Comment: 4. is not so awkward, as far as I can perceive.

Comment: @congliu  as I said, I am not a linguist, but a native speaker. For me, I rarely hear 4.

Comment: I'm native too, and I heard about it a lot.

Comment: @congliu 南北差异？你是南方的么？

Comment: 是的，在下南方人，敢問閣下是？

Comment: @congliu  哦，那可能是南北差异，小弟北方人。

Comment: 方才恕有冒昧 還望海涵 在此謝@perfectionm1ng兄賜教 :D

Answer (score 3):

看不起 - Derogatory term

看不上 - Neutral term

example:

> A boy likes a girl, but the girl doesn't like the boy.

girl 看不上 boy. boy isn't a bad person, just isn't attractive enough.

> A man stole something, so everyone hates him.

The man is really bad, so everyone 看不起 him.

Answer (score 3):

**看不起 + 某物品 (something)**

> 表示 觉得这个物品没有价值，不值得拥有。
>
> Indicates that you think that thing is worthless or not worth having

**看不起 + 某人 (someone)**

> 表示 觉得这个人某方面能力或某方面不好，带贬义。
>
> Indicates that you think this person is, in some respect, bad. Pejorative term.

**看不上 + 某人 (someone)**

> 觉得这个人不适合。 比如团队需要人，选择男女朋友时。
>
> You think this person is unsuitable. For instance, when a team is selecting new members, or when one chooses a boy or girl friend.

Comment: Hi fazhang. Welcome to Chinese SE. When you write Chinese, please provide the pinyin and English translation as not all of us can fluently read Chinese. Thank you

Comment: Where is the regulation that the question/answer must attach English translation? Not all of us can speak English fluently either. Mr @Growler.

Comment: @congliu Providing Chinese, pinyin, and English creates a standard that facilitates Q&A for native and non-native Chinese speakers. Moreover, this is a Chinese language learning Q&A site, so you would expect that it would pander to non-native Chinese learners. Several non-native learners have mentioned they would like English explanations, and often down vote if there are none.

Comment: Show us the link of the regulation, or it may be regarded as your own opinion. Mr @Growler.

Comment: @congliu It is an opinion shared by many Chinese SE users. As I expressed in my comment above, several users have down voted and requested mod support for this reason. Therefore, as a mod, I have added explanation that might clarify why their answers are getting down votes.

Comment: So it's your opinion. As anyone can say that "It is an opinion shared by many Chinese SE users" too. Shared by Who? Mr. @Growler.

Comment: @congliu I cannot disclose who. If you'd like, we can discuss this further in chat or you can pose a question on meta.

Comment: Downvote(s) cannot imply the wrongfulness of the question/answer sufficiently. As a downvoter may not follow the rule too. Mr @Growler.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/10645/discussion-between-growler-and-congliu)

Comment: Alright, discussion is always better than conflict, I'd like to help improve if needed. Moderator like you, Mr @Growler, is an very important role before our system becomes full-fledged. Thank you for concerning with my comments.

Comment: @congliu, I think there was a discussion somewhere on Meta. Though not mandated, if the question was asked in English, the answerer is expected to provide an explanation in English to be helpful to the OP. Maybe this could be highlighted on the FAQ since many people are answering without giving due consideration whether the OP can understand or not.

Answer (score 2):

**看不上**

> 没有达到自己的心理预估值，或者想要更好的
>
> He/she/it doesn't meet your expectations, or you want something/someone better

**看不起**

> 一点都没有看上
>
> No desire for, totally despise

Comment: Hi user3242. Please provide pinyin and English translation for long Chinese sentences. Most of us on this site are still learning Chinese.

Answer (score 1):

看不起 = look down upon, think negatively of, disapprove of, despise (someone)

看不上 = think (something or someone) is under one's moral standards, social status, or aesthetic standards.

Example:

He is evil and I despise him. 他是坏人，我**看不起**他。

She is out of my league, I don't think she will ever like me. 我配不上她，我想她**看不上**我。

Answer (score 1):

看不上 is a bit more mild than 看不起.

看不上 means someone does not meet your standards, but 看不起 means you look down upon someone or someone is disgusting based on your values and tastes, its emotion is stronger.

Answer (score 0):

看不起 : look down somebody because his value is low. based on a value judgement on him/her.

看不上 : will not accept/choose somebody because of many choices or better choices. based on demand on him/her.

Answer (score 0):

Using simple sentence and assuming 我 = a lady and 他 = him.

我看不上他 => I find him beneath my standards.
我看不起他 => I find him beneath my station.

marry beneath (one's) station
To marry someone who is of a lower social class or standing than oneself.
A: "I hear that Mr. Sullivan plans to marry a local fishmonger's daughter." B: "Why would a man of his esteem marry beneath his station like that?"
Janet has a bright future with one of the best law firms in town, so it's beyond me why she's marrying beneath her station with some fast food worker.