# What is the grammar behind "上去“ in 听上去不错?

Tags: grammar

An English translation of  "听上去不错" is "sounds good".

I understand ”不错“ as "not bad", i.e. "good" (the literal expression "not bad" is quite common in Britain and has the same meaning).

But I don't understand why and how "上去" function in this saying. Can someone please explain?

In more detail, I understand the individual meaning of these characters but not why together, with 听, they equate to "sound" in the phrase "sound good".

Comment: ＂上去＂ is a compound direction complement (复合趋向补语，others：上来、下去／来、进去／来、出去／来、回来／去、过来／去、起来、开来／去、到。。。。来／去）cf。＂实用现代汉语语法＂［上去］  **１。** 趋向意义（一）：表示人或物体通过动作，由低处向高处移动，立足点在底处。例如：（１）听见楼上＂嘭＂的一声，我赶紧跑上楼去。（我--楼下）（２）我看见一个孩子很快地爬上树去。（我--在树下）（３）他在楼上等着呢，你快把文件送上去。（说话人--在楼下） **２。**  趋向意义（二）：表示通过动作，人或物体离开立足点向另一处所移动。例如：用人听见主人叫他，他很快地走上前去问主人有什么事。（＂用人＂离开立足点）（２）一个电影明星来了，我看见很多孩子围了上去。（＂我＂的位置是立足点，＂很多还字＂离开立足点） **３。** 结果意义（基本结果意义）：表示接触、附着以至固定，着眼点在物体的部分或次要物体。也就是说表示通过动作，使物体的一部分或次要物体与整体或主要物体接触、附着以至固定。例如：（１）这副画儿很好看，你贴上去吧。（着眼点在＂墙＂）（２）我也报名，请你把我的名字写上去。（着眼点在＂表格＂）（３）那根绳子太短，把这根接上去。（着眼点在＂那根绳子＂）（４）屋子里灰尘太大，电视机容易脏，把这快布蒙上去。（着眼点在＂电视机＂）

Comment: ＂上＂的基本结果意义与＂上来＂、＂上去＂相同，但没有着眼点或着眼点不清楚。表示结果意义时，＂上＂比＂上来＂、＂上去＂更常用。 for 上 as direction complement see https://chinese.stackexchange.com/questions/21239/how-to-explain-usage-of-%e7%85%a7%e5%be%97%e4%b8%8a-%e7%ab%99%e5%be%97%e4%b8%8b  for special meanings of 看上去 see e.g. bkrs:it would appear it seems (that) it seems; it looks as if e.g. 他为何看上去如此凄伤?他看上去强健，其实他的心脏很衰弱。(for E translation and more examples see bkrs), also see previous Q&A:    https://chinese.stackexchange.com/questions/3624/whats-the-difference-between-%e7%9c%8b%e8%b5%b7%e6%9d%a5-and-%e7%9c%8b%e4%b8%8a%e5%8e%bb

Answer (score 1, accepted):

上去 here functions as preposition (to),  in this case, the object 'words' is omitted

听 (listen) + 上去 (to)

- (听**上去**)不错 = "It is not bad (listen **to** it)."

Example of other [verb +上去] phrases

- 看上去 (look at it)
- 摸上去 (touch on it)

*You can use 起来 instead of 上去 in this sentence
- (听起来)不错 = "It is not bad (listening to) it. "*

Comment: JFYI: I don't think you will ever hear 'listen onto', only 'listen to'. Maybe in the Bible you might find 'listen unto me'. You are Chinese I presume, so you know better, but wouldn't you rather say '听起来‘ instead of '听来’？

Comment: Some English and Chinese grammar structure do not  have corresponding counterpart to each other. 'onto' is the general meaning of '上去' . As you see  in example 摸上去. -- 听上去 should be more accurately translate as " upon listening to". Yes It should be  '听起来‘ instead of '听来’.  I should use 看来 to demonstrate  result complement

Comment: I would edit my answer

Answer (score 1):

> ... with 听, they equate to "sound" in the phrase "sound good".

This interpretation is not correct. 听 itself just means 'to listen'.

The word 'sound' is defined in merriam-webster dictionary:

> to make or convey an impression especially when heard; i.e. *it sounds
>   good to me*

"to make or convey an impression especially when heard" is the exact equivalence of 听上去 or 听起来 in Chinese.

听 is a verb. 上去/起来 is a verb complement here, expressing/implying what your impression is after you heard something or what you feel after you heard it.